# Alignment issue while using the Berkeley theme in Beamer

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I have an alignment problem with my frames when used in the `Berkeley` theme. The frame overlaps to the left hiding the bar behind. Could you help me to solve this. Please refer the screenshot.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
  {
    %\usetheme{Berlin}
  %\usetheme{Dreuw}
  %\usetheme{Warsaw}
  %\usetheme{Rochester}
  %\usetheme{PaloAlto}
   %\usetheme{Antibes}
   \usetheme{Berkeley}

   }
  \usepackage{times}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  \usepackage{ragged2e}

  \boldmath
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
  \graphicspath{{figures/}}
  \title[Fancy Posters]{Making Really Fancy Posters with \LaTeX}
  \author[Dreuw \& Deselaers]{Philippe Dreuw and Thomas Deselaers}
  \institute[RWTH Aachen University]{Human Language Technology and Pattern Recognition, RWTH Achen University}
  \date{Sep. 20th, 2014}


  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5
        \begin{document}
      \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{The UNIX Time Sharing System}

        \begin{block}{\large The UNIX Time Sharing System}

           \centering
           \vspace{18cm}
          %{\VeryHuge The UNIX Time Sharing System}\par
          \vspace{3cm}
          {\LARGE Dennis M Ritchie and Jen Thompson}\par
          \vspace{1cm}
          {\LARGE Bell Laboratories}\par
          \vspace{15cm}



          \hspace{45cm}{\Large Presented by }\par
          \hspace{55cm}{\normalsize Rohit Kiran}\par
          \hspace{60cm}{\normalsize AM.EN.P2CSN14008}\par

          \vspace{3cm}
        \end{block}
       \end{frame} 
        \vfill
        \vfill
```

[image: The first frame]

I am new to Beamer.

Comment: Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so they can replicate this problem on their own? The problem may depend heavily on the preamble content and how you're using the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `\setbeamersize{text margin left=<width>, text margin right=<width>}`. I used a 4cm margin in the following MWE (also removed some unused code)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
  {
   \usetheme{Berkeley}
   }
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
    \setbeamersize{text margin left=4cm, text margin right=4cm} %NEW CODE

  \graphicspath{{figures/}}
  \title[Fancy Posters]{Making Really Fancy Posters with \LaTeX}
  \author[Dreuw \& Deselaers]{Philippe Dreuw and Thomas Deselaers}
  \institute[RWTH Aachen University]{Human Language Technology and Pattern Recognition, RWTH Achen University}
  \date{Sep. 20th, 2014}

  \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The UNIX Time Sharing System}
    \begin{block}{\large The UNIX Time Sharing System}
     \centering
     \vspace{18cm}
     %{\VeryHuge The UNIX Time Sharing System}\par
     \vspace{3cm}
     {\LARGE Dennis M Ritchie and Jen Thompson}\par
     \vspace{1cm}
     {\LARGE Bell Laboratories}\par
     \vspace{15cm}
     \hspace{45cm}{\Large Presented by }\par
     \hspace{55cm}{\normalsize Rohit Kiran}\par
     \hspace{60cm}{\normalsize AM.EN.P2CSN14008}\par
     \vspace{3cm}
     \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked!!
Could you guide me on how to increase the width of the left margin and height of the top margin colored in blue; so that the frame fits into the main-frame that is behind.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I'm failing to understand what your goal is. You can increase the width of the sidebar using `\usetheme[width=<value>]{Berkeley}` (put any value you want inside). For the top bar, you need to customize the `headline` template. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: Is it possible to change the height of a block?

Comment: @RohitKiran the height of a block depends on its content, so in general you do not specify a height parameter. However the format of the site does not support asking more than one question at a time, so I encourage you to ask a new question about blocks height.